# ReactTable - How to Set Filtering?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I got some custom filtering and I want to set one the options to be the default filtering.

I thought what I need is "defaultFilterMethod" but I never it see it getting triggered(I put a console.log in it)

https://react-table.js.org/#/story/custom-filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project I use matchSorter and it works well:

```
<ReactTable
    ...
    defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) => matchSorter([row[filter.id]], filter.value).length !== 0}
    ...
/>
```

Comment: is matchsorter built in?

Comment: No, I installed it via npm

Comment: hmm, I will look into it but my issue is that it seems like defaultFiltermethod does not get triggered onload. I put a console.log in it and I never see the log.

Comment: did you use a filter to see something in the console?)